# Switch md-sidenav mode (Angular Material 2)

Tags: angular, menu, angular-material2

I'm interested in changing the `md-sidenav` - from Angular Material 2 - mode from side (for desktops) to over (mobile). Is there a way to change it programmatically?
Thanks

Comment: what do mean by side to over? Its not clear what you want

Comment: The md-sidenav has a mode, that could be "over", "push" or "side" (https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building on Steve G's solution you could update app.component.html

```
<md-sidenav [mode]="isLargeScreen() ? 'side' : 'over'" [opened]="isLargeScreen()"></md-sidenav>
```

And then in app.component.ts

```
isLargeScreen() {
  const width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  if (width > 720) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

This gives you a sidebar on desktop opened by default, and on mobile it overlays but is hidden by default!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by ObservableMedia.

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from "@angular/core";
import {ObservableMedia} from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public media:ObservableMedia ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

template:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav  mode="{{media.isActive('gt-sm') ? 'side' : 'over'}}" align="begin" class="md-whiteframe-4dp" opened >
      <md-nav-list>
        ...
      </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure!  You could do your screen width test (or browser detection, blech) in your component [on initialization](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html) and store the result in a variable as a string.

Using width detection as an example, you might do something like this:

**Partial app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') 
  private wrapperElement: ElementRef;

  private menuMode; // Where we'll store the resulting menu mode

  ngOnInit() {
    // Do your simple test on the container, for example
    if (this.wrapperElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth <= 720) {
        this.menuMode = "over";
    } else {
        this.menuMode = "side";
    }
  }
}
```

And bind the variable to the sidenav in the template.

**Partial app.component.html**

```
<div #wrapper>
    <md-sidenav-container>
        <md-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="menuMode"></md-sidenav>
        ...
</div>
```

The bulk of that work is just determining how you want to perform the test.

You could also just test window instead of a wrapper, but I prefer testing a wrapper.

**Notes:**

1. **This is untested code.**
2. This will fire only on initialization of the component, if you
   *also* want to handle the case where the user resizes their browser and the menu mode changes, you'll need to do something a little more
   fancy using [HostListener](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-interface.html) `@HostListener("window:resize",
   ["$event"])`, but that's outside of the scope of your original
   question.

Comment: I used the @ViewChild to get the MdSidenav element from the DOM, then I changed the mode directly from the sidenav. Thanks for the help!